# ref for attribute doesn't work on complex type under netbeans

Tags: xml, netbeans, xsd

I am learning XML and XSD, and i am having a problem. I want to validate the following XML document with the following XSD documents. Because the attribute "id" is used on two different elements. I wanted to separate his definition from the definition of store and client and then to use ref on it. Unfortunately, Netbeans seems to ignore ref on attribute or i am doing it the wrong way because when i check the file store.xml, i have the following error :

```
XML validation started.

Checking file:/Users/toto/NetBeansProjects/Cookbook/src/java/store.xml...
Referenced entity at "file:/Users/strokyl/NetBeansProjects/Cookbook/src/java/store.xsd".
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'client'. [14] 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'client'. [19] 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'client'. [24] 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'product'. [32] 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'product'. [39] 
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'product'. [46]
```

When i replace `<xs:attribute ref="id"/>` by the definition of the attribute of id on client and store, the xml valid correctly !

Thank you in advance for your precious help and sorry for my poor english (i am French).

The XML file (store.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    Document   : store.xml.xml
    Created on : 12 novembre 2013, 22:09
    Author     : strokyl
    Description:
        Purpose of the document follows.
-->
<store xmlns="http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation='http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store store.xsd'>
    <clients>
        <client id="1">
            <first_name>Luc</first_name>
            <last_name>Duzan</last_name>
            <age>22</age>
        </client>
        <client id="2">
            <first_name>Adrien</first_name>
            <last_name>Gareau</last_name>
            <age>22</age>
        </client>
        <client id="3">
            <first_name>Gilles</first_name>
            <last_name>Roudière</last_name>
            <age>22</age>
        </client>
    </clients>

    <products>
        <product id="1">
            <name>Poster de Maxime Médard</name>
  <!-- You don’t have to use same convention that you use for relational database -->
            <categorie>Poster</categorie>
            <price>10</price>
            <number_in_stock>100</number_in_stock>
        </product>
        <product id="2">
            <name>Poster de Yannick Jauzion</name>
            <categorie>Poster</categorie>
            <price>10</price>
            <number_in_stock>200</number_in_stock>
        </product>

        <product id="3">
            <name>Drapeau du stade toulousain</name>
            <categorie>drapeau</categorie>
            <price>5</price>
            <number_in_stock>500</number_in_stock>
        </product>
    </products>
</store>
```

The xml schema file (store.xsd)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store"
    xmlns="http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="store">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="clients"/>
                <xs:element ref="products"/>
                <xs:any/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

<!-- Definition très exposé de clients -->

    <xs:element name="first_name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="last_name" type="xs:string"/>

    <xs:element name="age">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer"/>

    <xs:complexType name="client_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="first_name"/>
            <xs:element ref="last_name"/>
            <xs:element ref="age"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="id"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="client" type="client_type"/>

    <xs:complexType name="clients_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="client" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="clients" type="clients_type"/>

<!-- Definition très condensé de product à part qu'on réutilise l'attribut id définit plus tôt -->
    <xs:element name="products">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="product" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="categorie" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="price">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>

                            <xs:element name="number_in_stock">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="1000"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>

                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute ref="id"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that top level attribute declarations take on the `targetNamespace` of the schema. Therefore the validator is looking for an attribute named `id` that is in the `http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store` namespace, but your document instead includes an attribute named `id` that is in *no* namespace (since a default xmlns declaration doesn't apply to attributes).

To be valid by your existing schema you'd need to bind a prefix to the namespace and use that prefix for the attribute

```
<store xmlns="http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store"
      xmlns:store="http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store">
  <!-- ... -->
  <client store:id="1">
```

By contrast, *local* attribute declarations inside a complex type are in no namespace (unless you specify `attributeFormDefault` on the schema or `form` on the specific declaration). So an alternative might be to declare a base type with the attribute and then have your other types extend that.

```
<xs:complexType name="identifiedType">
  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="client_type">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="identifiedType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="first_name"/>
        <xs:element ref="last_name"/>
        <xs:element ref="age"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The id attribute is now a local declaration rather than a global one.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, but just to make it simpler:

Actually the problem with attributes is that if you want to specify global declarations for reuse (I mean outside a complex type), you need to qualify the attributes in the xml instance where you are using them.

In your case, you will need to do the following within your store.xml instance:

1) add a prefix to your store declared name space, let's say "**xmlns:store="http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store"**" :

```
<store xmlns="http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xmlns:store="http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store"

    xsi:schemaLocation='http://etud.insa-toulouse.fr/~duzan/store store.xsd'>
```

2) Then you need to qualify the attributes, for instance **store:id** :

```
<clients>
    <client store:id="1">
        <first_name>Luc</first_name>
        <last_name>Duzan</last_name>
        <age>22</age>
    </client>
```

My suggestions :

- Why using attributes? Practices in SOA is use elements when it is possible (of course not everybody thinks the same ..)
- If you really need them, then only use local declarations of attributes (within the complex types) to avoid verbosing the namespaces within the instances.